# Entity Framework much slower than SSMS

Tags: performance, entity-framework

I have a super simple query

```
select  * from documents where id= 50189
```

This returns one pretty heavy row from `SQL Server`.  (about 30 MB). Execution time is between 30-120 seconds

but when I run the query via `EF`, it takes more than 10 minutes!

how can that be? and how can that be fixed?

here's the pretty basic EF code:

```
Dim d = GetSystemContext()
d.CommandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
Dim qry = d.Set(Of Document).AsNoTracking
Dim id = 50189
Dim a = qry.Where(Function(x) x.ID = id)
Dim cmd = a.GetCommand
Dim b = a.FirstOrDefault
```

any ideas anybody?

TIA!

Comment: You can use `AsNoTracking()` or linq to sql

Comment: If you have large blobs in your table SSMS won't fetch them completely, by default.  EF will.

Comment: @ilkerkaran I've tried `AsNoTracking` but it did not help. I've updated my post. also, I would need tracking in this case, it's in an editable window.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Hi. That's a very interesting point. Major. Now, how can I get the actual complete row in `SSMS`? So I can continue with the testing/comparisons? Thanks

Comment: It's better to compare using ADO.NET directly in code.  That's what SSMS uses, but you have full control.

Comment: ok cool. so it seems that the same issue exists in ado.net. if so, how can I improve the performance? My client can't wait 15 minutes for a window to open.. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, can you please make your comments as an answer so i can accept it? thanks!